# converting byte array to double - c

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to get the numerical (double) value from a byte array of 16 elements, as follows:

```
unsigned char input[16];
double output;
...
double a  = input[0];
distance = a;
for (i=1;i<16;i++){
    a = input[i] << 8*i;
    output += a;
}
```

but it does not work.
It seems that the temporary variable that contains the result of the left-shift can store only 32 bits, because after 4 shift operations of 8 bits it overflows.

I know that I can use something like

```
a = input[i] * pow(2,8*i);
```

but, for curiosity, I was wondering if there's any solution to this problem using the shift operator...

Comment: You haven't said what "input[16]" is trying to represent. Is it a 128-bit integral value, or something else?

Comment: Are you storing the number in "input" in the form of a 128bit unsigned integer?

Comment: @Roddy: from his algorithm it seems that the characters are the coefficients in a 15-th order polynomial (with base 256).  (@paolo_, is this right?)

Comment: as said by Adrian P., the input[16] vector is a sequence of bits that i want to represent as a 128bit unsigned integer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: this won't work (see comment) without something like `__int128`.

```
a = input[i] << 8*i;
```

The expression `input[i]` is promoted to `int` ([6.3.1.1](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf)) , which is 32bit on your machine. To overcome this issue, the lefthand operand has to be 64bit, like in

```
a = (1L * input[i]) << 8*i;
```

or

```
a = (long long unsigned) input[i] << 8*i;
```

and remember about endianness

Comment: Won't this still overflow once he tries to do the (<< 8*i) for the i>= 9 part of the loop since this loop seems to be trying to convert a 128bit value to a double, or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that indeed the 32 bit variables cannot be shifted more than 4*8 times, i.e. your code works for 4 char's only.

What you could do is find the first significant char, and use Horner's law: a<sub>n</sub>x<sup>n</sup> + a<sub>n-1</sub><sup>n-1</sup> + ... = ((...( a<sub>n</sub>x + a<sub>n-1</sub> ).x + a<sub>n-2</sub> ) . x + ... ) + a<sub>0</sub> as follows:

```
char coefficients[16] = { 0, 0, ..., 14, 15 };
int exponent=15;
double result = 0.;

for(int exponent = 15; exp >= 0; --exp ) {
   result *= 256.; // instead of <<8.
   result += coefficients[ exponent ];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In short, No, you can't convert a sequence of `byte`s directly into a `double` by bit-shifting as shown by your code sample.

`byte`, an integer type and `double`, a floating point type (i.e. not an integer type) are not bitwise compatible (i.e. you can't just bitshift to values of a bunch of bytes into a floating point type and expect an equivalent result.)

1) Assuming the byte array is a memory buffer referencing an integer value, you should be able to convert your `byte` array into a 128-bit integer via bit-shifting and then convert that resulting integer into a `double`. Don't forget that endian-issues may come into play depending on the CPU architecture.

2) Assuming the byte array is a memory buffer that contains a 128-bit long double value, and assuming there are no endian issues, you should be able to memcpy the value from the byte array into the long double value

```
union doubleOrByte {
    BYTE buffer[16];
    long double val;
} dOrb;
dOrb.val = 3.14159267;
long double newval = 0.0;

memcpy((void*)&newval, (void*)dOrb.buffer, sizeof(dOrb.buffer));
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply cast the array to a double pointer?

```
unsigned char input[16];

double* pd = (double*)input;

for (int i=0; i<sizeof(input)/sizeof(double); ++i)
    cout << pd[i];
```

if you need to fix endian-ness, reverse the char array using the STL reverse() before casting to a double array.

Comment: By far and away the simplest solution!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried std::atof:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atof/

Comment: I believe the input is not ascii, but actually a floating point value in a buffer.

Comment: Only relevant if the input is string format of a number, if he has dumped a double to memory and then loaded it as a char array this would fail.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to convert a string representation of a number to a real number? In that case, the C-standard atof is your best friend.

Answer (score 0):

Well based off of operator precedence the right hand side of

```
a = input[i] << 8*i;
```

gets evaluated before it gets converted to a double, so you are shifting input[i] by 8*i bits, which stores its result in a 32 bit temporary variable and thus overflows. You can try the following:

```
a = (long long unsigned int)input[i] << 8*i;
```

**Edit:** Not sure what the size of a double is on your system, but on mine it is 8 bytes, if this is the case for you as well the second half of your input array will never be seen as the shift will overflow even the double type.