# How to convert a byte array into double in C?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, type-conversion

I've got a byte array containing 8 bytes and would like to convert and use them as a double precision binary floating-point number.

Could someone please tell me how to convert it?

Comment: @Paul: Actually the best answer here thus far, shame it's only a comment :)

Comment: @PaulTomblin, maybe you all the other people suggesting this should form a union and protest against this particular use having undefined behavior.

Comment: Well, doing this in the first place is playing with fire.

Comment: possible duplicate of [converting byte array to double - c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301353/converting-byte-array-to-double-c)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this:

```
double a;
memcpy(&a, ptr, sizeof(double));
```

where `ptr` is the pointer to your byte array. If you want to avoid copying use a union, e.g.

```
union {
  double d;
  char bytes[sizeof(double)];
} u;
// Store your data in u.bytes
// Use floating point number from u.d
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `sizeof a`? :)

Comment: This question is tagged both C and C++.  In C the union version works, in C++ it causes undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 19):

Here is one solution using `memcpy` function:

```
double d = 0;
unsigned char buf[sizeof d] = {0};

memcpy(&d, buf, sizeof d);
```

Note that a solution like:

```
d = *((double *) buf);
```

shoud be avoided. This is undefined behavior because it potentially violates alignment and aliasing rules.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that the typical approach is unsafe and invokes UB for **two** reasons.

Comment: @R.: actually there's only one *reason* (namely "because the standard says so"), but indeed it is good to know the actual pitfalls which reckless casting can cause.

Comment: First time I have seen `sizeof d` rather than `sizeof(d)`

Comment: @LokiAstari `sizeof` is an operator and not a function. This the C syntax of `sizeof` when the operand is an expression. The parentheses are unneccesary. But they are required by the synatx if you use `sizeof` with a type name operand.

Comment: @ouah: I was aware that you could do it. I had just not seen it before. The worst part now is that I have to debate with myself which is clearer so that I can have a good usage and be consistent. Ba humbug my brain is too old and fixed for multiple choices.

Comment: What is the type of `(double *) buf`? I have never seen a cast from `uint8_t *` to `double *` like this. Can it be static_cast? reinterpret_cast? Would those work (aside from the alignment/aliasing)

Answer (score 10):

In C++:

```
double x;
char buf[sizeof(double)]; // your data

#include <algorithm>

// ...
std::copy(buf, buf + sizeof(double), reinterpret_cast<char*>(&x));
```

In C:

```
#include <string.h>

/* ... */
memcpy(&x, buf, sizeof(double));
```

In C++11, you can also use `std::begin(buf)` and `std::end(buf)` as the boundaries (include the header `<iterator>`), and in both languages you can use `sizeof(buf) / sizeof(buf[0])` (or simply `sizeof(buf)`) for the size, all provided `buf` is actually an array and not just a pointer.