# How to change constant value in linux dynamic library?

Tags: linux, assembly, reverse-engineering, x86-64

There is a dynamic library for 64-bit linux, it contains many functions compiled from from C++ code. The code is not open source, but I have an idea how one of the functions shoul look like. It contains mathematical expression and I would like to change one of the constants in this expression.

I have some programming skills, but never looked into compiled objects and executable. The relevant part of assembly code obtained by `objdump -RDC` command is below. The constant of interest should be of type `double` and it seems it is used in multiplication command in line `7e1cc`.

```
7e1b8:  00 
7e1b9:  f2 0f 59 74 24 78       mulsd  0x78(%rsp),%xmm6
7e1bf:  f2 41 0f 59 f0          mulsd  %xmm8,%xmm6
7e1c4:  f2 0f 58 ce             addsd  %xmm6,%xmm1
7e1c8:  f2 0f 58 ca             addsd  %xmm2,%xmm1
7e1cc:  f2 0f 59 0d fc 0e 0c    mulsd  0xc0efc(%rip),%xmm1        # 13f0d0 <typeinfo name for RestorableCreator<Model>+0x90>
7e1d3:  00 
7e1d4:  48 81 c4 88 00 00 00    add    $0x88,%rsp
7e1db:  66 0f 28 c1             movapd %xmm1,%xmm0
7e1df:  c3                      retq
```

I'd like to know how to find the position of this constant in the file, convert my constant to hex format and replace the value in the file to my hex value. Could anyone explain how to do this? Also suggestions about proper tools would be really valuable.

Comment: There's no floating-point constant on that line.

Comment: @H2CO3, could you please explain why? As far as I understand, the line contains only address of the constant, and it is not possible to tell the type of constant from this address

Comment: The form `0xc0efc(%rip)` is instruction-pointer relative addressing. The constant `0xc0efc` is interpreted as an offset, so it's an integer. That's the only constant on the line. Whether or not the value at the address is a constant or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constant is at address `0xc0efc(%rip)` where `%rip` is the address of the next instruction, meaning `0x7e1d4`. So the address is: `0xc0efc + 0x7e1d4 = 0x13F0D0` (objdump even prints that for you).
Now, examine the headers of your binary using `objdump -h`. That will list all the sections along with virtual addresses and file offsets. Find which section the address falls into, and calculate how far into the section it is, then add the file offset. Now use a hex editor to fetch the 8 bytes representing your double from that offset. Turn it into human-readable form by whatever means you want, for example by a trivial C program that just casts a byte array to double and prints it.

Comment: Thanks for explanations! In fact I found that this constant is exactly at offset `0x13F0D0` from beginning of the file, just jumped to this address in hex editor. Concerning converting byte array to double one can use this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8703047/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-into-double-in-c or online converter http://binaryconvert.com