# Convert char array to double using unions with all decimal places

Tags: c, double, precision, unions, bytebuffer

I'm porting a project from Java to C. I need to convert a byte (= char in C) array to double. I found a solution here on Stack Overflow using unions ([How to convert a byte array into double in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8703069/5244395)).

My code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
double getDouble(char array[], int size) {
    union {
        double d;
        char bytes[size];
    } result;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        result.bytes[i] = array[i];
    }
    return result.d;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char array[8] = {13, 67, -76, -39, -6, 59, -58, 63};
    printf("%f", getDouble(array, sizeof(array)));

    return 0;
}
```

This prints "0.173705". This looks just right, BUT the problem is, that converting a byte-array in Java to double using
`ByteBuffer.wrap(array).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getDouble();`
returns the double-value "0.17370544080815656".

I do need this high precision of the double. How can I achieve this in C?

---

**EDIT:**

Solution from the comments ([higher precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33329877/convert-char-array-to-double-using-unions-with-all-decimal-places#comment54456617_33329877)) ([faster code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33329877/convert-char-array-to-double-using-unions-with-all-decimal-places#comment54457021_33329877)):

```
double getDouble(char array[]) {
    double result;
    memcpy(&result, array, sizeof(result));
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char array[8] = {13, 67, -76, -39, -6, 59, -58, 63};
    printf("%.17f", getDouble(array));

    return 0;
}
```

This prints the Java-like "0.17370544080815656". I could even increase the precision.

Thanks to @user3121023 @ameyCU @Andrew Henle

Comment: @user3121023 this does the trick, thanks!

Comment: @user3121023: Why not make this an answer.

Comment: OT: `int size` would better be `size_t size`. Some for `int i`.

Comment: @ameyCU same result. Are there any advantages of using `memcpy` over `union`?

Comment: no ,no advantages IMHO @user3121023  gave the answer :-)

Comment: @ameyCU - One big advantage of `memcpy()` - it's already done, and it's one line of code:  `double d; memcpy( &d, array, sizeof( d ) );`  It's also quite likely to be faster, maybe even a lot faster.

Comment: @AndrewHenle IMHO ,endianess will play role there , won't it . I wont consider it has any advantage .

Comment: @ameyCU @AndrewHenle in my case, endianess is always little-endian. If `memcpy` is indeed "a lot faster", I will use it.

Comment: @ameyCU - It sure could.  But the OP's code already has an endianness dependency.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Well, yeah than it is good to go .

Comment: added solution to question.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: What makes you think it's faster or even a lot faster?

Comment: @cremno This:  https://fossies.org/dox/glibc-2.22/string_2memcpy_8c_source.html  And this:  http://src.illumos.org/source/xref/illumos-gate/usr/src/lib/libc/i386_hwcap1/gen/memcpy.s  Try beating those performance-wise with a simple loop you write.  Then benchmark your implementation against the OS-supplied one.  It wouldn't be surprising if you fail to get within an order of magnitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution from the comments ([higher precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33329877/convert-char-array-to-double-using-unions-with-all-decimal-places#comment54456617_33329877)) ([faster code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33329877/convert-char-array-to-double-using-unions-with-all-decimal-places#comment54457021_33329877)):

```
double getDouble(char array[]) {
    double result;
    memcpy(&result, array, sizeof(result));
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char array[8] = {13, 67, -76, -39, -6, 59, -58, 63};
    printf("%.17f", getDouble(array));

    return 0;
}
```

This prints the Java-like "0.17370544080815656". I could even increase the precision.

Thanks to @user3121023 @ameyCU @Andrew Henle